# Bluetooth Low Energy - sending packets very slow

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

We're building both a BLE device, and the mobile app to talk to it.  The mobile app is written in Xamarin/C#, with the Android stuff in an Android-specific PCL (Portable Class Library).

I've split my data into small chunks so it fits into the default 20-byte BLE packet size, I've got one data block that is 96 bytes long so I send it as 6 16-byte data packets.  I've set it up so the first 5 data blocks are sent with WriteType set to GattWriteType.NoResponse, and only the last data block has WriteType set to GattWriteType.Default.

For each of the first 5 data blocks I call SetValue() and WriteCharacteristic() and then wait for the OnCharacteristicWrite() notification to come before writing the next data block.  Doing this, I can write the first 5 data blocks in about 20 msec.  But then the 6th block (Write_With_Response) takes about 300 msec between the WriteCharacteristic() and the corresponding OnCharacteristicWrite() notification.

Is this an expected delay?  It seems awfully long!

Are there settings I need to tweak, to get the BLE write to happen faster?

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting API 21 and above I would try using requestConnectionPriority on BluetoothGatt to get a higher connection priority which should give you better speeds.

Comment: Setting that flag either has no effect on overall timing, or causes transmission problems.  I'm not surprised though, since there's only one Bluetooth conversation happening (on both the BLE device and the tablet), increasing the priority seems unlikely to help ...

Comment: That is surprising since we have gotten speed increases every time we have used it. We always use write with response though, because we have run into issues when we have used no response.